# Selenium 3.7.1 how to use wait.until() with Expected condition?

Tags: java, selenium, testing

With selenium 3.7.1 it's not possible to use wait.until() with Expected condition, just with `wait.until(Function<? super WebDriver, v> arg)`.
Example code working in another selenium version:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
```

After some search I found some users that added this dependency in maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>21.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After that the method is not returning the error, but when I try to build the log return:

```
[ERROR]required:java.util.function.Function<superorg.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V> 
[ERROR]found:org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.Alert>
[ERROR] reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) V exist so that argument type org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.Alert> conforms to formal parameter type java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver,V>
```

Anyone knows how to use the wait.until(ExpectedConditions)?

Comment: Can you show us your code trial with `ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()`?

Comment: What version of Java do you use?

Comment: I'm using java 1.7 @Rafał Laskowski

Comment: @DebanjanB what do you mean with code trial?all code function?

Comment: @FastDev The code block where you wanted to implement the ExpectedCondition clause along with the relevant HTML

Comment: @FastDev Take a look at this [thread](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/592)